# css positioning with display or float , can I get this structure using display property

Tags: css, css-float

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div1a"></div>
    <div id="div1b"></div>
    <div id="div1c"></div>
    <div id="div1d"></div>
</div>
<div id="div2a"></div>
```

Can I get this structure using CSS display property?

[image]

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: Short answer. Yes. As Jason said though, show us something that you've tried.

Comment: I've tried with div1a's width to be 1000px and the rest divs in div1 200px, then all the divs inside div1 float left, and div2aa float right. bt then div2 was not exactly as i've shown in the image but was out of div1. I jst wanted to knw if i can do this

Comment: I was actually trying it on firebug and was not sure it can be done, since @Blake said that it can be done http://jsfiddle.net/pahnin/m5JtK/ this is my code and structure, I dont know if i shud use float or display to bring div2 floating. anyone plz help. thnx.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m5JtK/1/ using some positioning, and likely not the only option. It's not perfect, and there are many possible issues. You'd probably have some more luck with a few more divs

Comment: thnx for the help, pat's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it can be done with the following CSS:

```
/* Height of the top box.  Change as needed to suit your layout */
#div1a {
  height: 50px;  
}

/* 3 left side boxes.  Again, alter the height/width as needed.  If you change
   the width, you'll need to update the margin-left on #div2a as well. */
#div1b, #div1c, #div1d {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;  

  /* This bit causes them to float to the left in a vertical row of boxes */
  float: left;
  clear: both;   
}

/* Increased height of the last box on the left */
#div1d {
  height: 200px;   
}

/* Main content box on the right.  min-height can be changed as needed. 
   The margin makes room for the 3 boxes floating down the left side. 
   You read its properties as margin: top right bottom left; */
#div2a {  
  min-height: 365px;  
  margin: 0 20px 0 140px;   
}

/* Generic margin/padding for all <div>'s */
div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Remove the generic margin for #div1 */
#div1 { 
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Demo of it](http://jsfiddle.net/s9AhU/) in action.

Comment: Yes, use this one. Looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
.mask{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4
}
.header{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4
}
.colleft{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   right: 84%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4
}
.col1{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   width: 82%;
   left: 101%;
   background-color: #e6e6e6
}
.col2{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   width: 14%;
   left: 3%;
   background-color: #e6e6e6
}
.footer{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #b4caf7
}
body {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   font-size: 90%;
   background-color: #e7e7de
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mask">
    <div class="header">
        DIV1A
    </div>
    <div class="colleft">
        <div class="col1">
            DIV2A
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div id="div1b">DIV1B</div>
            <div id="div1c">DIV1C</div>
            <div id="div1d">DIV1D</div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assuming from their question they wanted only with the given HTML, not with extra markup.

Comment: yes @Blake is right, I dont want to change the markup since I want to edit the css of existing theme for prestashop rather than editing the markup.